# Images inside a DIV (display: table-cell;) exceed the height

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, horizontal-scrolling, css-tables

I need to vertically align Images inside of horizontal layout with fluid height (100%). The most appropriate method to center vertically without a fixed height, I found so far, is to use  display: table, table-row and table-cell. With the following code, the centering works so far:

```
<div class="itemwrap">
  <div class="imagecenterrow">
  <div class="imagecentercell">
    <img src="..." title="...">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with

```
.itemwrap {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
.imagecenterrow {
  display: table-row;
}
.imagecentercell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.imagecentercell img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

The images seem to ignore the height of the table-cell DIV and are all displayed in their original sizes (exceeding the 100% height of the parent elements). The vertical cerntering works though. Any ideas on restricting the images to the boundaries of the table-cell? (They must not be cropped)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget, `max-height` and `max-width` will ONLY work in relaation to values defined on the same element for `height` and `width`, which you currently dont have set. You will need to define these in order for it to work, removing the `max-` part should work for you.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYn4t/1/)

[**More on `max-height` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height)

> The max-height CSS property is used to set the maximum height of a
>   given element. It prevents the used value of the **height** property from
>   becoming larger than the value specified for max-height.

Answer (score 0):

set the max-height of the image to a value that is less than table's height

```
.itemwrap img {
max-height: 5px;
}
```

just edit 5px

---

you can even add internal spaces using **padding**

```
.imagecentercell img {
padding: 10px!important;
}
```